# How can I replace a class name using jQuery when I just know the start characters of the name?

Tags: jquery

I have:

```
<tr id='id1' class='X-** other-class a-class'>
```

Where the * can be any number.

If I want to replace the class name that starts with X-99 then how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
if ($('#id1').get().className) {
    $('#id1').get().className = $('#id1').get().className.replace(/\bX\-.*?\b/g, 'X-99');
}  else {
    $('#id1').addClass('X-99')
}
```

Comment: I realize my problem. If there is no class already defined for the element it gives an error. Is there a way I can make this happen only if there's a class already defined? Otherwise I get className is null error. I know I could maybe add a dummy class like <tr class='dummy'> but this doesn't seem a very clean way to do it.

Comment: @Gemma yes, you can use an if statement to check whether the element has a class or not, try the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try those selectors:

```
// all trs with X-* class (that is: classes which starts with X-)
$("tr[class^='X-']") 

// all trs with X-99 class
$("tr.X-99")
```

Then you can use `addClass` or `removeClass` to set or unset classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(".X-99").removeClass(".X-99"); //class level
jQuery("#id1").removeClass(".X-99"); //id level
```

what do you want to do exactly ?